# Signing in with Game center

Tags: objective-c

I had integrated my app to apple game center. On launching my app, it prompts for game center login. I canceled the login process and continued game. When i click high score, it shows a dialog to sign in. I redirected my app to game center app. After logging in, is it possible to write code to switch back to my app.

Comment: it is not possible to navigate back to your app from another app, unless that other app is also developed by you. In iOS 9, apple provided a way to navigate back to your app when you move to another app from your app.

Comment: Thanks Mr. T. I think it will work for me in IOS 9.

Comment: Sorry. The back to app button which is added in IOS 9, will redirect only if we stay on the same page. But in my case after signing in, it redirects to home screen in game center. So I think it will not work....